# React says props."function" is not a function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ajax, react-redux, typeerror

I'm making my first webshop and I have a problem. I made fake API where I have my data of product cards, and when I use `axios.get` to get them and add to state, I catch "props.addCardData is not a function". I must say that all worked fine until I added `axios.get`. Other functions I used the same way as function `addCardData`: I mean, I used `mapDispatchToProps`, I used `props.addCardData` - I didn't use them in `axios.get` or other requests). I didn't have problems with any function before.

I planned to get data by `axios.get`, call a function from cards container that will call dispatch with action creator as parameter.

I also catch 'Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'addCardData').

Below, I have indicated the parts of the code that are affected by the problem (I have indicated which code applies to which elements)

This is code in Cards component (I didn't add imports here, but ofc I have all imports):

```
const Cards = (props) => {

  axios.get('https://mocki.io/v1/8cb0f160-92f7-4cf8-a6c1-f63690df514e')
    .then(response => {
      props.addCardData(response.data)
    })

  let cardsArray = Object.keys(props.cardsData).map(card => (
    <OfferCard
      key={card.id}
      bg={props.cardsData[card].bg}
      id={props.cardsData[card].tagId}
      title={props.cardsData[card].title}
      text={props.cardsData[card].text}
      button={
        <Container fluid>
          <Row className={'row-cols-auto'}>
            {props.cardsData[card].button.map(button => (
              <CardsButton
                key={button.id}
                link={button.link}
                type={button.type}
                class={button.class}
                name={button.name}
              />
            ))}
          </Row>
        </Container>
      }
    />
  ))

  return (
    <Container fluid>
      <img src={'./backgrounds/bestoffers.png'} alt={'BEST OFFERS'} className={'img-fluid imgTab'} />
      <Row xs={1} md={2} id={'cards-row'} className={'border border-4 g-3'}>
        {/*row-cols-* - set the cards width by setting amount of cards in row*/}
        {cardsArray}
      </Row>
    </Container>
  )
}

export default Cards
```

This is code in `CardsContainer`:

```js
const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
  return {
    cardsData: state.homePage.cardsData
  }
}

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {
  return {
    addCardData: (data) => {
      dispatch(addCardsData(data))
    }
  }
}

const CardsContainer = connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(Cards);

export default CardsContainer
```

This is code in reducer:

```js
...
homePageCardsData = 'HOMEPAGE-CARDS-DATA'

initialState = {...} - includes "cardsData: {}"

const homePageReducer = (state = initialState, action) => {
  let stateCopy;
  switch (action.type) {
    case homePageCardsData: {
      stateCopy = {...state, cardsData: action.data}
      break
    }
    ...
    default: return state;
  }
  return stateCopy;

  ...... - some functions here (not necessary to know)
}

export const addCardsData = (data) => ({
  type: homePageCardsData,
  data: data
})
```

When I try something like that:

```js
const addCard = props.addCardData

axios.get('https://mocki.io/v1/8cb0f160-92f7-4cf8-a6c1-f63690df514e')
  .then(response => {
    addCard(response.data)
  })
```

I get lags on localhost (on MAIN PAGE!!), all starting to render slowly and 70% of cases, block of cards is not rendered. In other cases, it can render after a while (very little chance). On AdminPanel page, where I render `Cards` because I need to see changes when I am testing menu, I get "TypeError: addCard is not a function."

If I delete this code from my component - it all works.

I must also say that I used "debugger" and put it in case `homePageCardsData`. Scripts stops on debugger (after `StateCopy` and before `break`). It means that script is correct, `dispatch` works and I can get into case `homePageCardsData`.

Comment: Can you make an example here? https://codesandbox.io/s/react-new

Answer (score 0):

The issue is in the `Cards` component where it's making the Axios GET request as an unintentional side-effect directly in the function body of the component. This may very well be creating a render loop, or at a minimum is issuing a GET request each and every time `Cards` renders.

Move this code into a `useEffect` hook so it's called after the component mounts.

Example:

```
const Cards = ({ addCardsData, cardsData }) => {
  useEffect(() => {
    axios
      .get("https://mocki.io/v1/8cb0f160-92f7-4cf8-a6c1-f63690df514e")
      .then((response) => {
        addCardsData(response.data);
      });
  }, [addCardsData]);

  let cardsArray = Object.keys(cardsData).map((card) => (
    <OfferCard
      key={card.id}
      bg={cardsData[card].bg}
      id={cardsData[card].tagId}
      title={cardsData[card].title}
      text={cardsData[card].text}
      button={
        <Container fluid>
          <Row className={"row-cols-auto"}>
            {cardsData[card].button.map((button) => (
              <CardsButton
                key={button.id}
                link={button.link}
                type={button.type}
                class={button.class}
                name={button.name}
              />
            ))}
          </Row>
        </Container>
      }
    />
  ));

  return (
    ...
  );
};

const mapStateToProps = (state) => ({
  cardsData: state.homePage.cardsData
});

const mapDispatchToProps = {
  addCardsData
};

const CardsContainer = connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(Cards);
```

You are using rather legacy Redux code, we don't generally use the `connect` Higher Order Component anymore since the `useDispatch` and `useSelector` hooks replaced its usage. The current standard now is to use [`Redux-Toolkit`](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/), which ***really*** cuts down on the amount of boilerplate you need to write.

Here's an example update suggestion:

```
import { useDispatch, useSelector } from "react-redux";
...

const Cards = () => {
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  const cardsData = useSelector(state => state.homePage.cardsData);

  useEffect(() => {
    axios
      .get("https://mocki.io/v1/8cb0f160-92f7-4cf8-a6c1-f63690df514e")
      .then((response) => {
        dispatch(addCardsData(response.data));
      });
  }, [dispatch]);

  let cardsArray = Object.keys(cardsData).map((card) => (
    <OfferCard
      key={card.id}
      bg={cardsData[card].bg}
      id={cardsData[card].tagId}
      title={cardsData[card].title}
      text={cardsData[card].text}
      button={
        <Container fluid>
          <Row className={"row-cols-auto"}>
            {cardsData[card].button.map((button) => (
              <CardsButton
                key={button.id}
                link={button.link}
                type={button.type}
                class={button.class}
                name={button.name}
              />
            ))}
          </Row>
        </Container>
      }
    />
  ));

  return (
    ...
  );
};
```

The reducer code, action types, action creators... all replaced by a single state slice.

```js
import { createSlice } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";

const initialState = {
  cardsData: {},
  ... other home page state ...
};

const homePageSlice = createSlice({
  name: "homePage",
  initialState,
  reducers: {
    addCardsData: (state, action) => {
      state.cardsData = action.payload;
    },
    ... other reducer cases ...
  }
});

export const {
  addCardsData,
  ... other generated actions ...
} = homePageSlice.actions;

export default homePageSlice.reducer;
```

[image: Edit react-says-props-function-is-not-a-function]

Comment: @KvartalMan Welcome, glad to help. Did this answer actually address/resolve your question/issue?